# want to store data in the reactJs for faster access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, fetch, service-worker

What i want to achieve is when the user log in,the data gets loaded on the first instance the **data is of around 30mb**.So the next time the same user access the website the data should get loaded from the front end rather fetching the same data from backend which is quite large and will take 1 minute in fetching the data.Is there any way by which we can store data in the react js.

Comment: It takes 2 seconds to download 1 MB?

Comment: it depends on the network,in my previous application it takes 50 secs to download the data

Answer (score 0):

**A warning before providing some solutions to your problem**: A payload of 30mb is quite large for a web application. I recommend being mindful of user connectivity. A resource providing some useful stats on connectivity: https://ourworldindata.org/internet.

With regard to caching a large amount of data in your React app, there are a couple of options. Mozilla's [Client-side_storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage) is a good place to start looking. That being said, I don't think there are any options that allow you to store over 50mb client side.